# Can "Animate Rope" be used on a spiked chain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am making a wizard who mostly uses the environment around him to attack, with spells like *Animate Object*. Currently I want to have him carry a spiked chain with him for his *[Animate Rope](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/animateRope.html)* spell. I know that the spell specifically says the rope cannot be used to harm, and it never mentions chains as a target. Does this mean it won't work as a restraint, or can it still be used to tie up opponents, and whenever they struggle to escape they take 1d4 piercing damage?

Comment: Please clarify from which perspective you want to hear the answer. I'd say, RAW: no, Realism: why not, Balance: Yes, but deals no damage. Ultimately it's up to your DM to decide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The chain is certainly a *rope-like* object, and so can be the subject of an *[Animate Rope](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/animateRope.html)* spell. However you cannot use Animate Rope to tie up a resisting opponent. A subdued opponent would be fine, but an opponent actively struggling and resisting cannot be restrained by the Animate Rope spell. Instead, what happens is the opponent becomes *[entangled](http://paizo.com/prd/glossary.html#entangled)*.

What happens whilst entangled with a spiked chain isn't covered in the rules. A little common sense can be applied though. The rules do state no damage is done by the rope whilst entangling, as mentioned by @DanRasmussen, but that is most likely damage from constriction. It's not unreasonable to expect the chains to do damage whilst entangling a struggling opponent. Whilst this will be entirely up to your DM, if this was my call I would rule that the chain does damage on the initial entanglement, and then again on every subsequent failed escape attempt, or every burst attempt (successful or not).

Comment: +1 for clarifying the differences between *restraints* and *entanglement*.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, I would argue that you can animate a chain, as it is "*rope-like*."**

However, a spiked chain probably has a diameter of more than an inch. As a GM, I would consider the spikes when determining the overall diameter. This reduces the length of chain that can be animated.

Secondly, you cannot consider your chain a "rope" for the purpose of being animated, then argue that it is not a "rope" in order for it to do damage. When it says "the rope does not deal damage," however, the description is referring to the rope/chain being thrown *near* the opponent, since it must be within one foot in order to entangle. Afterwards throwing the chain near your opponent, you can force them to make a reflex save to avoid being entangled. After entangling, the spell allows for no extra damaging effects, tho your GM may rule that the spikes do indeed damage the entanglee.